# How do I store a list in a dictionary when it is being created then cleared and then used for the next key with different values?

Tags: c++, string, list, dictionary

What I really want is to have the values to each key be an arbitrary list that is accessible for later use. The code given is just a sample of what is being attempted.

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <map>

int main(){
  std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> myMap;
  std::list<std::string> myList;
  int j = 0;
  while(j<4){
    for(int = 0; i < 6; i++){
      myList.push_back("value");
    }
    myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::list<std::string>("Key", myList));
    myList.clear();
    j++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you use `std::make_pair`

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want. Just to reuse `myList` in each iteration. The next example works because the list is let's say reset at the beginning of each while loop, and then copied into the map: https://godbolt.org/z/M1P4oYsG1

Comment: I've posted an answer using a `std::move(myList)` instead of a copy. That should save you a list copy for each map insertion.

Comment: @rturrado Thank you! I see what you are doing and I am trying to impliment it. On this example and the one with std::move(myList), say I declare a variable of type string; How do I use the value of the variable to become the key using the map subscript operator as you did?

Comment: Addition: https://godbolt.org/z/rG3MaW5E6

Comment: You got it right in your link. Just use `myMap[key]`. The idea would be the same as with `myList`. Declare the string as close to its use as possible. Then you can also move it if you're not going to use it anymore within the loop: https://godbolt.org/z/f383reK7z

Comment: @rturrado You are amazing and thank you for your time!

Comment: No probs, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to reuse `myList`: 1) move the list declaration inside the `while` loop, so that a new empty list is created in every iteration, and then 2) use the map subscript operator with an rvalue reference so that the list is moved into the map.

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <map>

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> myMap{};
  int j = 0;
  while (j < 4) {
    std::list<std::string> myList{};
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      myList.push_back(std::string{"value"} + std::to_string(j) + std::to_string(i));
    }
    myMap[std::string{"Key"} + std::to_string(j)] = std::move(myList);
    j++;
  }

  for (auto&& [key, list_value] : myMap)
  {
      std::cout << key << ": ";
      for (auto&& str : list_value)
      {
        std::cout << str << " ";
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T1doM746W)